# Why is my Python instance being shared?

Tags: python

My code:

```
class Num:

    nums = []

    def add(self, num):
        self.nums.append(num)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.nums)

a = Num()
b = Num()
a.add(5)
print str(a)
print str(b)
```

produces

```
[5]
[5]
```

even though nothing has been added to b

Answer (score 8):

Because nums is a class attribute and not an instance attribute.

```
class Num:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = []

    def add(self, num):
        self.nums.append(num)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.nums)
```

Implementing it like this will show the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Num:
    nums = []
```

Defining `nums` in the class definition statement makes `nums` a class variable. Define it in the `__init__` method instead, by setting it as an attribute of the instance:

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self): # self is the instance
        self.nums = []  # setting nums on the instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `nums` an empty list that is an instance attribute

```
class Num:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = []

    def add(self, num):
        self.nums.append(num)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.nums)
```

then

```
a = Num()
b = Num()
a.add(5)
b.add(6)
print str(a)
print str(b)
```

gives

```
[5]
[6]
```